# Как динамически изменить ширину прогресс бара svg

Tags: javascript, svg

Есть косой прогресс бар на svg:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <polygon fill="red" points="100 100, 200, 80, 200 100, 100 120"/>
  <polygon fill="yellow" points="100 100, 140, 91, 140 112, 100 120"/>
</svg>
```

Как динамически изменить прогресc, а именно координаты желтого прогресс бара относительно красного ? Если у прогресса 100%, то желтый занимает всю ширину и тд

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так, при помощи сдвига clip-path:

```js
let clip = document.querySelector('clipPath polygon');
let progress = v => clip.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${v},0)`);
addEventListener('mousemove', e => progress(e.y/innerHeight*100));
```

```html
<svg viewBox="100 70 100 50" height=160px>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip">
       <polygon  points="100 70 200 70 200 120 100 120"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <polygon fill="yellow"  points="100 100 200 80 200 100 100 120"/>
  <polygon fill="red" clip-path="url(#clip)" points="100 100 200 80 200 100 100 120"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: все супер, только такой вопрос, как узнать в js ширину полигона внутри clipPath, т.е. эти самые 100px ?

Comment: @Amandi а зачем?

Comment: чтобы изменить логику отображения под проценты, например так, https://jsfiddle.net/7uk18vmp/

Comment: @Amandi так то тут и так проценты =)

Comment: да :) но это вообще возможно, чтобы знать ширину внутри js ?

Comment: @Amandi у Svg своя систем координат, а все изображение просто растягивается до заднного размера